# Change text in multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#, forms, loops, for-loop

How would I go about making a for loop that changes the text in more than 1 textbox?

```
for (int i; i < 5; i++) 
{
    textbox(i).text = "something"
}
```

But I don't know how to get the I to represent the number after the textbox, does anyone know how to?

Comment: use controls.find :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Controls.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var txts = this.Controls.Find("textbox" + i, true); // true for recursive search
foreach(TextBox txt in txts)
    txt.Text = "something";
```

or - if the `TextBoxes` are in the same container control(like the `Form` or a `Panel`)- with LINQ:

```
var txts = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(txt => txt.Name == "textbox" + i);
foreach(TextBox txt in txts)
    txt.Text = "something";
```

Actually you don't need the loop variable, you could also use `String.StartsWith` to get all:

```
var txts = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(txt => txt.Name.StartsWith("textbox"));
foreach(TextBox txt in txts)
    txt.Text = "something";
```

Answer (score 3):

Store the textboxes in an Array and then loop over the array

```
for (int i; i < 5; i++) 
{
    textboxArray[i].text = "something"
}
```

Comment: How would I create an array of my textboxes?

Comment: @WincyGaming, `var textboxArray = new[] { textBox1, textBox2, ... };`.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to alter every textbox on your form just simply add them to a List:

```
List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
TextBoxes.Add(This.TextBox1);
TextBoxes.Add(This.TextBox3):
```

then as others have suggested you could either linq or regular foreach the textboxes in the list

```
TextBoxes.Foreach(Textbox => TextBox.Text = "something");
```

or

```
foreach (TextBox r in TextBoxes)
{
    r.Text = "something;
}
```